# Is falsity both true and false?

Tags: logic

I have been thinking about the liar's paradox a lot lately (which I will post about soon), and I've run into a seemingly unrelated paradox. Consider this sentence: Falsity is both true and false.  Symbolizing the sentence one way yields: F=T&F.  This is a true statement because T&F simplifies to F.  Symbolizing another way yields: (F=T) & (F=F).  This statement is false.  So my question is whether the sentence is a legitimate paradox or whether the different truth values come from an ambiguity in the English language.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: Liars Paradox is game theory, not philosophy.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda That is definitely not the received view within mainstream philosophy.

Comment: This is not a paradox. What you discovered is that A ≡ B&C and (A ≡ B)&(A ≡ C) are not logically equivalent propositions, where "≡" is logical equivalence. Specifically, when A is F, B is T and C is F we get different truth values. So (A ≡ B&C) ≢ (A ≡ B)&(A ≡ C), equivalence does not distribute over conjunction. This should not be surprising. The second one implies that B ≡ C, but there is no such requirement in the first. So you are "symbolizing" two different things and getting a mismatch. Perhaps they do sound similar as said in English, so one could attribute it to language ambiguity.

Comment: F=T&F is not an English sentence. It is a formula in Boolean algebra and the "rules of the game" are exactly those: False & whatever is False. This does not mean that False is also "whatever".

Answer (score 2):

It is true that ⊥ is equivalent to ⊤∧⊥, so that ⊥↔(⊤&⊥) is true. However, **we cannot distribute the biconditional across the conjunction**; ↔(&) is not in general equivalent to (↔)&(↔), and in particular we cannot conclude from the above that the sentence (⊥↔⊤)&(⊥↔⊥) is true. Indeed, this latter sentence is **false**.

So there is no paradox.

---

In terms of the natural language you've employed, the issue is that "Falsity is both true and false" can be interpreted in two ways:

- as "the conjunction of 'true' and 'false' is false," which is true; or
- as "falsity is true and falsity is false," which is false.

These two interpretations are not the same, and the conflation of them amounts to the claimed distributivity above.

Comment: I interpreted the OP’s assertion not as distributing the biconditional, but going from T & F to (F <-> F) & (F <-> T), by substituting (F <-> F) for T and (F <-> T) for F. The OP did note your “latter sentence” is false (assuming he meant the biconditional rather than equality).

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan I've added a bit of explanation about where I'm getting this interpretation of the OP. (Of course ultimately this is pretty good evidence that the OP should explain themself more clearly.)

Comment: I see, and I agree.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvote?

Comment: It wasn’t me. I didn’t downvote your answer nor the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposition is undefined until you specify what logic it is under. It seems, at a glance, you want to work in propositional logic, but propositional logic does not have equality. Most logical systems don’t. The closest thing in propositional logic is the biconditional “<->”.

Now, F <-> (T & F) is True, but this does not mean that F and (T & F) are the same. It merely means they have the same truth value.

“Falsity” is not both True and False. The truth value of F has the same truth value as (T & F) after simplification, but that is a much weaker assertion.

Your paradox is due to a lack of formalism and due to ambiguity in your language.